# Redirect to external link without appending the link to the current url

Tags: angular

In my template i have a click method to determine if the user will be routed to an external link or to the router link:

```
<div (click)=openLink(link, isExternal)>
```

In my component:

```
openLink(link, isExternal) {
    if (isExternal) {
        window.open(link, '_blank');
    } else {
        this.router.navigate([]).then(() => window.open(link, '_blank'))
    }
}
```

Example of links are:

```
external link:  'www.google.com'
router link:  '/listing'
```

But when it's an external link, it opens a new tab with the url:

```
http://localhost:4200/wwww.google.com
```

It's appending the external link to the current url.  How to set the url to be just `www.google.com`?

Comment: Are you sure your external link is not starting with `/` ?

Comment: Yes, very sure.

Comment: I got it.  The link should be `http://www.google.com` and not just `www.google.com`